# Selenium + JUnit + Maven extending a class query

Tags: java, maven, selenium, junit4

This is a strange one which has be scratching my head.

I have (or will have) a large number of tests which all use the same Before and have a Rule included.  So I thought what I could do was move this in to a "base" class.

So all was going well.  I created  some files which had a single @Test method.  I then tried creating a file which had muiltiple @Test methods (pretty much going to google and that is it.)  In Eclipse, this works as I expect.  When I try to run the same in maven, only one of @Tests in the multiple file goes to google, the others show nothing (the url seems to be set to "data;")  On the output maven shows "**GuidancePage_Test.GuidancePageTitleTest  NoSuchSession no such session**"

I am using JUnit 4.12:

and my Test is defined as:

```
public class GuidancePage_Test extends TestBase {
@Test

public void GuidancePageNextButtonPresentTest() throws InterruptedException {

ConfigReader cr = new ConfigReader();
url             = cr.getConfigString("Config/Test/Test.properties", "test_URL");

parameters      = WebDriverSteps.currentDriver;

steps.openWebPage(url);

steps.logToReport("Hello World");


}   
}
```

Base Test Class

public class TestBase {

```
public WebDriverSteps steps;
public String url = null;

/**
 * @brief Error Collector
 *
 * We use the ErrorCollector to collect all errors and present them at the end of the test.
 * This allows, for example, in data testing for us to have a complete run of all data before 
 * getting a test fail.
 * 
 */
@Rule
public ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();     

@Rule
public TestWatcher screenshotOnDemand = new TestWatcher() {
    @Override
    protected void succeeded(Description description) {
        steps.makeScreenshot();
    }

    @Override
    protected void failed(Throwable e, Description description) {
        steps.makeScreenshot();
    }

    @Override
    protected void finished(Description description){
        steps.quit();
    }

};

@Before
public void setUp() {
    steps = new WebDriverSteps();
}

//@Parameter("Browser")
public String parameters;
```

}

Comment: Please post your `TestBase` class.

Comment: @jsheeran - updated question with the code - the comment was limited in characters and couldn't get it to fit.